# Turn off trade email confirmation

Tags: steam

I do a fair amount of TF2 trading on steam through sites like backpack.tf. Every time I want to send or confirm trade offers steam sends me an email which I have to click in order to confirm the trade. This is annoying because I have to do it a lot. Is there any way to disable this or configure it such that I don't have to do an email confirmation every time?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The actual trade offers are handled by Steam. I have to click on "send trade offer" before steam will send the email. The email seems to me a pointless double confirmation - I've already indicated that I want to trade by clicking "send trade offer" so why should I have to confirm twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Visit your Inventory page.

   [image: Your Profile Name > Inventory]
2. Click *More* > *Inventory Privacy Settings*

   [image: More > Inventory Privacy Settings]
3. Set *Confirmation of Trades* to *Disabled* and hit *Save Changes*

   [image: Confirmation of Trades]

Note, by disabling email confirmations, you are forfeiting your rights to having your items recovered if your account is compromised. Make sure you have a strong, unique password on both your Steam account **and email account**.

Comment: Aha, I knew there was a security issue involved. Valve is nothing if not paranoid/conscientious about security.

Comment: Well they have over 125 million users and scams are becoming more and more of a problem, so it's quite difficult for their small support team to have to deal with so many scams.

Answer (score -1):

Although @Keavon cleared in some small steps, if you want to see the detailed guide here is a link I found.
[How to activate / deactivate email for Steam Trade / Steam Offers](http://www.dotainternational.com/Thread-How-to-Activate-Deactivate-Email-Verification-for-Steam-Trades-Steam-Offers)

Comment: Please summarize the information contained in the link.  That way, if ever that page goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, it saves people a click. :)